# Add a column containing a Task ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, tasks

I have created tasks in my SharePoint. Now I want to add a column called Task ID Number beginning with Year.
For Instance; Whenever I create a new task, it will generate an ID Number like 2017-001, 2017-002, 2017-003 and so on.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In your list, Try to create a calculated field with the following formula

```
=YEAR(Created)&"-"&ID
```

**To create a calculated column**

- Open your Task List
- List Settings
- Add new column with data type `Calculated (calculation based on other columns)`
- add the above formula.

**OutPut**

[image]